# How do I write contents to file in perl

Tags: perl, file-handling

When I try to write contents to a file the file comes back blank. Not sure what's going on here. I know the regex is working. I suspect the problem is with the way I write files.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
@files = </home/vnc/Downloads/test/*.json>;
my $myfile;
foreach $file (@files) {
    print $file . "\n";
    open(IN,'<',$file) or die $!;
    while(<IN>) {
        $_ =~ s/^(.*?)\[//;
        $_ =~ s/\](?=[^.]*$)//;
        $myfile = $_;
        # print $myfile;
    }
    close(IN);
    open(OT,'>',$file) or die $!;
    while(<OT>) {
        print(OT $myfile);
    }
    close(OT);
    # $file =~ s/^(.*?)\[//;
}
```

Comment: I've not seen `print(OT $myfile);` used before.  The standard notation has no parentheses: `print OT $myfile;`.  You should be using `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to make sure you aren't making any silly mistakes.  I'd also recommend the use of lexical file handles: `open my $in, '<', $file or die "Failed to open $file ($!)";` etc.

Comment: no worries, i figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, your approach is wrong. You process the whole file doing a replacement of some content with regular expressions but you are not writting it to any place. Later you open a file in write mode but the loop is useless because it's empty.

The easiest way to handle this situation, in my opinion, is to use the `$^I` variable that modifies files in place. Here an example as a one liner (**not tested**):

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/^(.*?)\[//; s/\](?=[^.]*$)//' /home/vnc/Downloads/test/*.json
```

Comment: Well spotted; I missed the obvious!

Comment: The script works fine once I implemented the suggestions in the comments under my question. I'm avoiding the one liners for now as I intend to do more regex processing and shell commands in one go.

Comment: @Julian: You can get the same behaviour using the variable `$^I` and processing files from `@ARGV`, if the one-liner scares you. It will avoid many headaches once you get used to it.

Comment: You do not have to forgo a source file just because you use the one-liner tools, you can just store the regexes and whatever code you want to have in the one-liner in a file, and run it without the `-e` switch, with file name arguments: `perl -pi yourfile.pl /home/vnc/Downloads/test/*.json`

Comment: i actually just use "perl exp.txt" when I'm running the script. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Julian Well, the point is that you can write your script much simpler and smaller when using the `-p` and `-i` switches. Your 20 lines of code would be reduced to two lines.

Answer (score 1):

To modify a list of files in-place from within a perl script, you could also use this approach. The file contents are loaded to array `@content`, modified and then written out to the original file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

# Example: Modifying a list of files in-place within a perl script

foreach my $file (</home/vnc/Downloads/test/*.json>) {
    # Open read-write (+<)
    open my $f, "+< $file" or die "$!\n";

    # read the lines:
    my @content = <$f>;

    # change the lines:
    @content = map { s/foo/bar/; $_ } @content;

    # empty the file
    truncate $f, 0;

    # rewind to beginning of file
    seek $f, 0, 0;

    # print new content to file
    print $f @content;

    close $f;
}
```